# Uploading Zipped folder Using Ajax Upload

Tags: javascript, zip, ajax-upload

In my site I want to upload a zipped folder using ajax.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
     var btnUpload=$('#file_mod');
        new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
            action: "index.php",
            name: 'file',
            onSubmit: function(file, ext){
            //alert(file);
                if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif|JPG|PNG|JPEG|GIF)$/.test(ext))){
                    // extension is not allowed 
                    return false;
                }           
            },
            onComplete: function(file, response){
            alert("success");
            }
     });
 </script>
```

But I don't know how ajax is used for zipped file uploading.

What should I change in my code?

Comment: Have you tried adding all of the file extensions for zipped files to the regular expression in your code? `jpg|png|jpeg|gif|zip|JPG|PNG|JPEG|GIF|ZIP` should add .zip files to the list of accepted ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this code you should add .zip extension to your allow list.

```
if (! (ext && /^(zip|ZIP)$/.test(ext))){
    // extension is not allowed 
    return false;
}
```

Now it should also upload zip files.

Hope this answer helps you in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The code checks the file extension in the function for the onSubmit option.
As you only allow image extensions the zip file is rejected as not being an image.

You need to add the extensions to the if clause like that:

```
if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif|JPG|PNG|JPEG|GIF|ZIP|zip)$/.test(ext))){
    // extension is not allowed 
    return false;
}
```

There are other types of zipped formats, don't forget to add these you're able to support.